# Get values as list from PHP array to use with Google Charts

Tags: php, arrays, google-visualization

I am pretty new to PHP and I am trying to use the googlechartphplib...

The api requires data to be entered in the form:

```
$data = new GoogleChartData(array(3450,800,700,5,50,67,1000,1250,900));
```

Long story short I have a PHP array that, when using:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($usersteps, true) . '</pre>';
```

looks like:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 3450
        [1] => 800
        [2] => 700
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 50
        [5] => 67
        [6] => 1000
        [7] => 1250
        [8] => 900
     )
```

What I am not sure about is getting a list values that seems to work with GoogleChartData; any ideas?

I've tried implode(), and the formatting looks correct but that results in a string and doesn't seem to work.

`array_values($usersteps)` just returns `Array`.

I'm sure it's straightforwards but I am not sure which function to use get the array data to work with GoogleChartData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use:

```
$data = new GoogleChartData($usersteps);
```

GoogleChartData need an array and you have one :)

Comment: That would do it! Thanks... I got stuck running in circles trying to format an array that was already there.